# Classes set dynamically in the 'host' property of directive are not being applied to the parent template in angular 8

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am implementing sorting in an angular 8 app using ng-bootstrap table following the sample here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable In the sample once I point my cursor on the header of the table, it changes to hand pointer with the class applied highlighted on the right in image below

[image]

Once I click on the header, an arrow appears on the left of the header value and the class which is responsible for it is highlighted on right in the image below

[image]

If we check the code in the table-sortable.ts file, these styles are coming from the 'host' property of directive as shown in the image

[image]

I am using the same directive in my angular app but the styles are not being applied to the header element. The sorting works but once I point cursor to header, the pointer cursor is not shown and after clicking on the header, the arrow is not shown although class="asc" is added to the header element as shown in the below image. The classes which are highlighted on the right in the above images are not there on the right here.

[image]

I can't figure out why the styles are not applied. I also set 'ViewEncapsulation' to 'None' in the parent component but the styles still don't apply. Please help me out with this.

Comment: you want arrow by default?

Comment: Not by default. If I click on any header then the arrow should appear showing whether content is sorted in ascending order or descending order as shown in the sample in the link I mentioned

Comment: Have you defined the styles `th[sortable].desc:before` and  `th[sortable].asc:before` in your css?

Comment: I added the styles to scss file of root app module but they din't work. I moved those styles to global styles.scss file and it works now. Thank you so much

Comment: @suvenk, It think you should answer your own question so that it can help other persons in the future.

Comment: Ya sure. I answered it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I added the required th[sortable].desc:before, th[sortable].asc:before and other necessary CSS classes in global style.scss file and it works now.